# New C++ Mongo driver: how to see type and how to get string value

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I've got two questions that I cannot find an answer for in the tutorial.

I get a document and then an element from the doc like this:

```
        bsoncxx::document::element e = doc["id"];

        if (!e || e.type() != bsoncxx::type::k_int32) return ERROR;
        int id = e.get_int32();
```

Is there a way to get a string value for the type, for debugging purposes?
Like:

```
        std::cout << e.type() << std::endl;
```

(which doesn't work)

The second question is how to convert the utf8 type value into a std::string.
This doesn't work:

```
        e = doc["name"];
        if (!e || e.type() != bsoncxx::type::k_utf8) return ERROR;
        string name = e.get_utf8().value;
```

Any tips?

Comment: Did you have a look at the doxygen documentation for `bsoncxx::type` and `bsoncxx::element`? http://api.mongodb.org/cxx11/r3.0.0/annotated.html

Answer (score 10):

1. Printing Type as string ([LIGNE 67](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/types.hpp))

   ```
   #include <bsoncxx/types.hpp>

   std::string bsoncxx::to_string(bsoncxx::type rhs);`
   ```
2. element to std::string

   ```
   stdx::string_view view = e.get_utf8().value;
   string name = view.to_string();
   ```

   - [stdx::string_view](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/stdx/string_view.hpp)
   - [std::string_view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view)

Comment: These are the correct answers, if not very clearly presented.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bsoncxx/types.hpp>

std::cout << bsoncxx::to_string(bsoncxx::types::b_utf8::type_id);
```

result: "utf8"

And these are type of bsoncxx

```
namespace types {
struct b_eod;
struct b_double;
struct b_utf8;
struct b_document;
struct b_array;
struct b_binary;
struct b_undefined;
struct b_oid;
struct b_bool;
struct b_date;
struct b_null;
struct b_regex;
struct b_dbpointer;
struct b_code;
struct b_symbol;
struct b_codewscope;
struct b_int32;
struct b_timestamp;
struct b_int64;
struct b_minkey;
struct b_maxkey;
class value;
}  // namespace types
```