# Get OID (types::b_oid) as string in MongoDB C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm using MongoDB C++ driver (version 3.4.0 for reference). I need to get the `_id` of a given document. First, I grab the document:

```
bsoncxx::stdx::optional<bsoncxx::document::value> sub = conn["mydb"]["csubs"].find_one(...);
```

so I can access to the `_id` this way:

```
sub->view()["_id"].get_oid();
```

So far, so good.

As far as I have read [in driver API](http://mongocxx.org/api/mongocxx-3.4.0/classbsoncxx_1_1document_1_1element.html#a6d85e9efb058d1441fc45c185ac535a2) this object is of type `types::b_oid`. However, I would need to get it as `std::string`.

Surprisingly, I haven't found any method in [the `types::b_oid` class documentation](http://mongocxx.org/api/mongocxx-3.4.0/structbsoncxx_1_1types_1_1b__oid.html) for string conversion. I mean, the typical `to_string()` method so I can call something like:

```
sub->view()["_id"].get_oid().to_string();
```

Probably I'm missing something (because the use case seems to be too obvious :), but after a while checking documentation I haven't find the solution. Any help is welcome!

Comment: There are two  ways depending whether you're trying to print as string or to convert value to string. Please see duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920720

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can call `to_string()` from the `value` field:

```
sub->view()["_id"].get_oid().value.to_string();
```

Here's an example from the [mongocxx github repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/eccd8b0a525f72d85d6153085e299c291d02acec/examples/mongocxx/get_values_from_documents.cpp#L95)